# Get all elements of the upper or lower triangle of a square matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function in numpy/scipy that returns all the elements of one of the triangles (upper or lower) of a square matrix?

e.g.:

```
matrix = [[1,  2,  3],
          [4,  5,  6],
          [7,  8,  9]]
```

triangles (upper and lower):

```
up = [1,2,3,5,6,9]
down = [1,4,5,7,8,9]
```

or

```
up = [1,2,5,3,6,9]
down = [1,4,7,5,8,9]
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Yes there are two functions that help you do that: `np.triu_indices(n)` (for the upper triangle) and `np.tril_indices(n)` (for the lower triangle).

Thanks katrielalex!

Comment: Usually, matrices are split at the main diagonal into an upper and lower triangle matrix.  This is also what the related NumPy functions do.  Does the choice of diagonal matter?

Comment: I basically want to slice the matrix by its diagonal, and then keeping either the upper or the lower triangle (including the diagonal). The function np.diagonal() only returns the elements of the diagonal of the matrix.

Comment: The point is that your examples use the diagonal from the lower left corner to the upper right corner, which is pretty strange.  All related NumPy functions (including `numpy.diagonal()` use the main diagonal, i.e. the diagonal from the upper left corner to the lower right corner.  So my question is:  Do you really need to use the "wrong" diagonal?

Comment: Actually I don't care. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I will edit the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the order of the elements matter?

Normally the upper and lower triangles of a matrix are taken about the *other* diagonal (top left to bottom right). To fix that, you need to "flip" between the two diagonals, which you can do with `np.fliplr(matrix)`. That will get you the correct elements, but in the "natural" order (row-by-row, with each row getting shorter). You can also get the column-by-column order by flipping the other way (`np.flipud`). But I don't know any way to get the "reading by smaller diagonals" order that you are using, short of reading the matrix one diagonal at a time.

To get the diagonal elements you can get their indices with `np.triu_indices` (or, for the lower triangle, `np.tril_indices`) and then index by them.

```
>>> matrix
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.fliplr(matrix)[np.triu_indices(3)]
array([3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 7])
```

Comment: Documentation for [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)

Answer (score 2):

The following code extracts the lower-triangle including the diagonal:

```
hstack(mat[i][:i+1] for i in xrange(mat.shape[0]))
```

and this extracts the lower-triangle without the diagonal:

```
hstack(mat[i][:i] for i in xrange(mat.shape[0]))
```