# Python - How to get the sum of the upper triangle of a matrix without using numpy?

Tags: python

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839836/get-all-elements-of-the-upper-or-lower-triangle-of-a-square-matrix-in-python) but I want to know how to do this without using numpy.  How can I get the summer of the upper triangle of a matrix with pure Python?  So for example, I have

```
matrix = [[1,  2,  3],
          [4,  5,  6],
          [7,  8,  9]]
```

How could I return:

```
upper = [2,3,6]
upperSum = 11
lower = [4,7,8]
lowerSum = 19
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What would your approach to this algorithm problem be?

Comment: Hint: `matrix[0][1] == 2`. Now, which indices correspond to each element of the upper triangle? How might you iterate over them?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>For square matrices:</strike> Actually I think it behaves correctly even for non-square matrices.

```
>>> m
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> sum(( m[i][i+1:] for i in range(len(m)) ), [])
[2, 3, 6]
>>> sum(( m[i][:i] for i in range(len(m)) ), [])
[4, 7, 8]
```

(Using the *sum-flatten* hack)

```
>>> sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is example of code:

```
matrix = [[1,  2,  3],
          [4,  5,  6],
          [7,  8,  9]]
upper = []
lower = []
for j in xrange(0, len(matrix)):
    for i in xrange(0, len(matrix)):
        if j>i:
            lower.append(matrix[j][i])
        elif j<i:
            upper.append(matrix[j][i])
        else:
            pass
upperSum = sum(upper)
lowerSum = sum(lower)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that this will only work if every sub array has the same length.

```
def GetSum(array):
    total = 0
    #Set the default value of "total" to 0.
    for i in range(len(array)):
    #for every item in the array:
        total += array[i]
        #Append the current selected value in the array to the total.
    return total
    #Return the total
try:
    length = len(matrix)
    #Get the length of the "matrix" array.
    rowlength = len(matrix[0])
    #Get the length of rows (the sub arrays within the main array).
    upper = [matrix[0][rowlength-2],matrix[0][rowlength-1],matrix[1][upperlength-1]]
    #Get the upper corner of the matrix array.
    uppersum = GetSum(upper)
    #Get the sum of all the items in "upper".
    lower = [matrix[length-2][0],matrix[length-1][0],matrix[length-1][1]]
    #Get the lower corner of the matrix array.
    lowersum = GetSum(lower)
    #Get the sum of all the items in "lower".
except:
    print("Incorrect matrix dimensions :/")
    #print an error message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
upper = []
[upper.extend(matrix[i][i+1:]) for i in range(len(matrix))]
lower = []
[lower.extend(matrix[i][0:i]) for i in range(len(matrix))]
```

And then do sum :-)

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with `sum` and generator expression:

```
matrix = [[1,  2,  3],
          [4,  5,  6],
          [7,  8,  9]]

size = 2
sum(sum(matrix[i][-size+i:]) for i in xrange(size)) # 11
sum(sum(matrix[-i-1][:size-i]) for i in xrange(size)) # 19
```

Comment: whats the size variable?

Comment: @JustinBrousseau: It's the size of the triangle, in this case it defines that we're taking 2 items from the first row which in upper triangle case would we `[2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagonal is matrix[x][x]. So your upper triangle is everything in matrix[x][x + n] with x < n < (matrix[x].length - x)
In the same way your lower triangle is in matrix[x][x - n] with 0 < n < x

So basically, just two for loops will do the thing :

```
for(i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j < (matrix[x].length - x); j++){
        //your code, here we iterate on the upper triangle
    }
}
```

I'm sure you will now find how to do the same on the lower triangle !

Answer (score -1):

```
A=np.random.randint(2,9,(6,6))
upper = []
lower = []
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    upper.extend(A[i][i+1:])
    lower.extend(A[i][0:i])
Uppersum = sum(upper)
Lowersum = sum(lower)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.