# Sum specific entries in matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like your help with the next problem.

I have an adjacency matrix as numpy array:

```
np.array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
          [ 1, 0, 6, 0],
          [ 2, 6, 0, 1],
          [ 3, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Then I want to sum weights of the edges between the list of nodes, e.g.:

```py
sum_edeges_between_list([0,1]) = 1 # only one entry, matrix[0,1]
sum_edeges_between_list([0,1,2]) = 9 # sum of three entries, matrix[0,1] +  matrix[0,2] +  matrix[1,2]
sum_edeges_between_list([0,1,2,3]) = 13 # sum of all entries above main diagonal
```

How can I do that?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.ix_](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to get the relevant part of array and calculate the sum.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
          [ 1, 0, 6, 0],
          [ 2, 6, 0, 1],
          [ 3, 0, 1, 0]])


def sum_edges_between_list(a, L):
    """
    >>> sum_edges_between_list(a, [0,1])
    1
    >>> sum_edges_between_list(a, [0,1,2])
    9
    >>> sum_edges_between_list(a, [0,1,2,3])
    13
    """
    return (a[np.ix_(L, L)].sum() / 2).astype(a.dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain, combinations
def all_subsets(ss):
    return list(chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(0, len(ss)+1))))

matx=np.array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
          [ 1, 0, 6, 0],
          [ 2, 6, 0, 1],
          [ 3, 0, 1, 0]])

def sum_edeges_between_list(ls):
    comb = [i for i in all_subsets(ls) if len(i)==2]
    return sum([matx[i[0]][i[1]] for i in comb])


print(sum_edeges_between_list([0,1]))
print(sum_edeges_between_list([0,1,2]))
print(sum_edeges_between_list([0,1,2,3]))
```

Output:

```
1
9
13
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using some on-board tools and a bit of slicing?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
              [ 1, 0, 6, 0],
              [ 2, 6, 0, 1],
              [ 3, 0, 1, 0]])

def sum_edeges_between_list(ics):

    # crop the elements using the upper-triangle function and slicing
    a = np.triu(x[ics[0]:(ics[-1] + 1), ics[0]:(ics[-1] + 1)], 0)

    return a.sum()
```

Careful: This takes only the first and last element of the list passed and sums the elements between them.

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378148/how-to-find-the-sum-of-elements-above-and-below-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix-in-pyth).